# Change matadata of pdf exported from Google Drive on the fly

Tags: pdf, google-drive-api, cpanel

I have a url in my website that opens a pdf page that is loaded from Google Drive using `https://docs.google.com/document/d/[document id]/export?format=pdf` url, using a simple php readfile code. However, the generated pdf does not have metadata such as Title, Author, and Description.

What is the best way serve the pdf with the updated metadata?

#### Caveats:

1. The website uses a shared cPanel web hosting.
2. I cannot install perl modules.
3. The host doesn't provide [native php pdf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) support, and I don't have access to composer.
4. The only supported server-side languages are perl and php.

The only acceptable solution I found was using [ConvertApi](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-pdf), which has a very limited free account (1500 seconds). However, I can get around that by caching the pdf and either retrieving a new copy when it's been over a day since the it was last updated or when I pass an argument to force it to re-cache.

Do you recommend any other solutions? I very much rather have set-it-and-forget-it solution.
Or is 1500 seconds enough for a file that is rarely going to be used?